# Embeding youtube video into a UIWebView - Volume Bar not Showing

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, ios7

I have an `UIWebView` where i'm loading an youtube `URL` using

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame
{
 NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@<div align=\"center\"><iframe width=\"290\" height=\"345\" src=\"%@\"></iframe></div><p><font size=\"2\">CATEGORY: <b>%@ , VIDEO</b></font></p></body></html>",[[self articleDetail] encodedContent_iPhone],url,[[[self articleDetail] category] uppercaseString]];
[[self articleDetailWebView] loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
}
```

Where everything works fine, but the **Volume Bar** BELOW the **PLAY icon** is not appearing in iOS 7, but it's coming in iOS 6. 
[image]